# ZF3 Create SELECT query from expression

Tags: php, postgresql, oop, zend-framework3

I want to create a ZF3 **\Zend\Db\Sql\Select** object where table is pgsql expression:

```
generate_series('2017-01-01'::date, '2017-02-01'::date, '1 day'::interval)
```

but if I pass expression as **\Zend\Db\Sql\Expression** object, like this:

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$select->from(['dd' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("generate_series('2017-01-01'::date, '2017-02-01'::date, '1 day'::interval)")]);
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend\Db\Sql\Expression could not be converted to string
```

but if I pass my expression as string, it's getting automatically wrapped and looks like this:

```
SELECT "dd".* FROM "generate_series('2017-01-01'::date, '2017-02-01'::date, '1 day'::interval)" AS "dd"
```

which is of course wrong. Is it possible to achieve without overwriting ZF3 Select class?

Answer (score 1):

`Select::form()` method takes table name as its argument. You may try this way:

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$select->columns(['AliasName' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("YourExpression")]);
```

This would produce following query:

```
SELECT YourExpression AS "AliasName"
```

**Updated**

The working example of the above method is down here. First, create an instance of database adapter providing database information. In this case, we are using `PDO` driver for `Postgresql`.

```
$adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter([
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Pgsql',
    'database' => 'YourDatabaseName',
    'username' => 'YourDatabaseUsername',
    'password' => 'PasswordForDatabase',
]);
```

Next up, we are going to create an another instance of `Sql::class` from `zend-db` component. It is not mandatory if you are using `TableGateway::class` in your controller action.

```
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($adapter);
```

Now here is the one you want, the `Select` object, which we are creating from the previous `Sql` object. Here we are also querying through `zend-db`'s `Expression::class` to generate some date series.

```
$select = $sql->select();
$select->columns(["dd" => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("generate_series('2007-02-01'::timestamp, '2007-03-01'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval)")]);
```

If we output the sql as string we would then get as the following

```
SELECT generate_series('2007-02-01'::timestamp, '2007-03-01'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) AS "dd"
```

As we are using PDO driver for postgresql, we would prepare the statement at the moment, and finally execute the sql.

```
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

If we output the results we fetched we would then get a series of dates as the following

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    print $row['dd'] ."</br>";
} 

// Outputs
2007-02-01 00:00:00
2007-02-02 00:00:00
2007-02-03 00:00:00
2007-02-04 00:00:00
...
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: I really need to SELECT FROM (expression), select expression as column is unfortunatelly not the answer.

Comment: Would you tell us what type of results, not query, are you expecting from that exact expression?

Comment: List of dates in provided range.

Comment: Also I would like to JOIN with rows that the series generate. For example SELECT * FROM (series_expression) s LEFT JOIN some_table st ON st.date = s.date. I need that to generate statistics of something over the given interval. Second table can but musn't have corresponding row.

Comment: Did my answer make any sense? If you want to join then you can use as `$select->join('some_table', 'st.date = s.date', ['column1', 'column2'] //optional, $select::JOIN_LEFT);`

Comment: Unfortunatelly you cannot join table with an expression that is called as one of the result columns. That's why so imortant to me to put expression as table which we select from.

Comment: You may [ask for here](https://discourse.zendframework.com/) for what you want. I hope you would get some help there.